# Including phonegap.js breaks javascript

Tags: jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

First of all, let me say that this is my first phonegap app so go easy on me ;)

I am building a mobile app using jquery mobile and phonegap build, and from what 
I've read in the docs, I should include phonegap.js in the index files of my app, but doing so seems to break my javascript code.

My app does some AJAX calls to a service on a remote server using jquery mobile and JSONP format, and if I include phonegap.js doing:

```js
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

Those calls do not work anymore.. Not sure what happens but I've checked the logs on the remote server and nothing wrong shows up there.

Any ideas? 
I need to use the device object so I definitely need to include phonegap.js..

I've only tested on android so far (Samsung Galaxy SII).

thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
example of the AJAX calls that do not work once phonegap.js is included:

```js
$.getJSON(app_domain+'service/dailydose.php?jsoncallback=?&d='+day).done(function(d){
            if(d.ok){
                //generate the HTML                 
                var html = '<div>retrieved data details</div>';
                $('body').append(html);
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have to assume that the calls you are making using the device object are causing the rest of your scripts to break. Not including the phonegap.js tag will allow the app to work because the device just skips over the device calls. Can you show more code so I can assist further?

Comment: for now the code is just using regular `$.get();` jquery calls, its not using the device object yet.

Comment: Include some code samples of where things are breaking please.

Comment: i've added an example of the ajax calls

Comment: So when you don't put the phonegap.js script tag in your <head></head> it works fine but when you do it breaks? And just to be clear, you are putting the phonegap.js script tag in your <head></head> and not actually putting a phonegap.js file into your director structure correct?

Comment: Any chance you could put the relevant parts of your project into codepen.io or jsfiddle.net so I can take a closer look?

Comment: thanks for the interest, i've finally found the cause of it, turns  out the service that my app was addressing was sending a text/html header while it should have been application/javascript (for JSON-P). 
Somehow this didnt make phonegap.js happy (no idea why though). Thanks again!